# How to remove an "append element"?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am appending a span with onclick. I cant change this because I am getting an HTML via PHP from another website.

So, I am adding in a table some informations like this:

```
            function getdados(id) {
              $('#loader').fadeIn();
              $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: 'index.php',
                data: { action: 'getdados', id: id },
                success: function(response) {
                    if(count > 1) {
                        $('.remove').remove();
                        console.log(count);
                    }
                    response = response.replace(/\+/g, '%20');
                    var str = response.split("%");
                    var cval = str[0];
                    for (var i = 1; i < str.length; i++) {
                        cval += String.fromCharCode(parseInt(str[i].substring(0,2),16))+str[i].substring(2);
                    }
                    jQuery.event.trigger("ajaxStop");

                    $('.resultados').append(cval);

                    var titles = $(".title").map(function() { return $(this).text(); }).get(),
                        dados  = $(".dados").map(function() { return $(this).text(); }).get(),
                        header = $(".headertitle").map(function() { return $(this).text(); }).get();

                    for(var i = 0; i < dados.length; i++) {
                        switch(titles[i]) {
                            case 'Naturesa: ':
                                titles[i] = 'Natureza: ';
                                dados[i] = dados[i] + ' - ' + dados[i+1];
                                dados.splice(i+1, 1);
                                titles.splice(i+1, 1);
                                break;
                            case 'DOC: : ':
                                titles[i] = 'DOC: ';
                                break;
                            case 'Atividade primária: ':
                                dados[i] = dados[i] + ' - ' + dados[i+1];
                                dados.splice(i+1, 1);
                                titles.splice(i+1, 1);
                                break;
                            case 'Atividade secundária: ':
                                dados[i] = dados[i] + ' - ' + dados[i+1];
                                dados.splice(i+1, 1);
                                titles.splice(i+1, 1);
                                break;
                        }
                        $('#results-2 table').append('<tr class="remove"><th>'+ titles[i] +'</th><td>'+ dados[i] +'</td></tr>');
                    }

                    for(var i = 0; i < header.length; i++) {
                        var link = $('.headertitle').eq(i).nextUntil('.headertitle').map(function() {
                            if(this.localName == 'span')
                                return '<tr class="remove"><td colspan="2">'+this.outerHTML+'</td></tr>';
                        }).get().join('');
                        $('#results-2 table').append('<tr class="remove rowTable"><th colspan="2">'+ header[i] +'</th></tr>'+link);
                    }

                    $('#loader').fadeOut();
                },
                error : function(transport) {
                    jQuery.event.trigger("ajaxStop");
                }
            });
        }
```

I need to remove all tr class="remove" from the table, but I think it is not possible :(

Someone can help me?

Comment: Why should it not be possible? O.o

Comment: Hint: Select the elements by class with jquery...

Comment: @Izkata He's already doing exactly this right at the beginning of the success handler: `if (count > 1) { $('.remove').remove(); }`

Comment: @Andreas I did a quick skim and missed that, but did see the append at the bottom.  But then I don't understand the question, "how do I do what I'm already doing?" ?

Answer (score 0):

Replace the following code:

```
$('#results-2 table').append('<tr class="remove rowTable"><th colspan="2">'+ header[i] +'</th></tr>'+link);
```

With this way, which has a handle to it:

```
var $tr = $('<tr class="remove rowTable"><th colspan="2">'+ header[i] +'</th></tr>' + link);
$tr.appendTo('#results-2 table');
```

Keeping the `$tr`, you can reuse using:

```
$tr.remove();
```

Or, the old school way, you can find the `.remove`:

```
$("tr.remove").remove();
```

If I don't understand your question, may be you just need to remove the class `remove` from the elements, use:

```
$("tr.remove").removeClass("remove");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this line to remove the tr with class remove.

```
jQuery("tr.remove").remove()
```